# Include a mixin inside a mixin

Tags: ruby

I'd like to do something like this:

```
module Mixin
  def self.included(base)
    base.include AnotherMixin
    ...
  end
end
```

which gives the error

```
NoMethodError - private method `include' called for Class
```

How can I include a mixin inside a mixin to use in the methods I'm defining?

Comment: just remove the `base` from `base.include AnotherMixin`... It will work.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - It will include AnotherMixin withn Mixin - try checking it with `included_modules`

Comment: @BroiSatse *How can I include a mixin inside a mixin* means what then ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit you're right -- feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit - Ah! Misread that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I include a mixin inside a mixin to use in the methods I'm defining?

As the error message is clearly telling you, `#include` is a *private* method, so *explicit receiver* is not allowed, in Ruby. Thus to get this done, you just need to remove the `base`, from the method invocation of `#include`. It will include the module `AnotherMixin`, inside the module `mixin`. Now, `#include` is being called, by an implicit `self`, which has been set to the module object `Mixin`.

Below will do the work :-

```
module Mixin
  def self.included(base)
    include AnotherMixin
    #...
  end
end
```